# Entity Framework generic Where for entities that inherit from a specific class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Here I have a generic Repository class I copied from a tutorial page, but specifically my problem is on the two last functions. On my project I have several catalog entities that inherit from CRUDProperties class and there is a property "Activo" in all of them, what I currently want to do is that if the entity inherits from CRUDProperties class I get all the entities with Activo property on true, and if they do not inherit from that class it just gets all entities. But the compiler throws an error stating T is already defined. What should I do?

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly projectEntities context;
    private IDbSet<T> entities;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    public Repository(projectEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public T GetById(object id)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    // This is the function that throws me a compilation error
    public virtual IList<T> GetAll<T>() where T : CRUDProperties
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Where(c => c.Activo).ToList();
    }

    public virtual IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        return context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have a type parameter `T` in the surrounding class `Repository<T>`. If you want to add a new / different type parameter to a method within that class then you'll need to give that type parameter a different name.

Comment: @bassfader so it can be assigned any other letter if I intend this to be as generic as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this method you can pass custom where clause to to your GetAll Method

```
public virtual IList<T> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

---

In this method we first check if the T type have Activo property, If find this property so we create a custom expression tree and replace with default predicate that returns all records, this function only returns records that have true value in activo property.

```
public virtual IList<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = t => true;
    if(typeof(T).GetProperty("Activo") != null)
    {

        var epx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression left =  Expression.PropertyOrField(epx, "Activo");
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(true);
        Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { epx });
    }
    return context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: This seems really useful, but is there a way that the predicate is applied automatically when the entity is inherited from a specific class? That is mostly my intention.

Comment: use reflection, check if your generic type has "Activo" property generate a predicate for this property and use as where cluase

Comment: could you expand your answer with an example? I have found how to get if an entitiy inherits from a class, but I can't access the entity properties

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about the ambiguous naming of the type parameters. The class already has a type parameter named `T`, so in the context of the class that type parameter name is already "taken".

But you should be able to accomplish what you want to do simply by renaming the type parameter for the method to something else than `T`, so your changed method could look like this:

```
public virtual IList<TCrud> GetAll<TCrud>() where TCrud : CRUDProperties
{
    return context.Set<TCrud>().Where(c => c.Activo).ToList();
}
```

Note: I assume here that `CRUDProperties` is a class... If it is an interface then you'll also need to copy the `class` constraint to the method (i.e. change it to `where TCrud : class, CRUDProperties`)